# Jenking added a '+' symbol as part of my command to be executed which failed

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My jenkins job seems to have failed for a very weird reason. When i saw the console output I could see  the '+` being added.

I tried to look through the bash reference manual but couldn't find much of an explanation to this issue I am seeing : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS1

Comment: `tee change.json` I would guess your file has dos line endings or other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The '+' symbols in your Jenkins console output are part of the Jenkins' way of showing that a command is executed. Especially when `set -x` is enabled.

The issue with your command is likely due to using `tee` to write to the same file you're reading from with cat. This can cause problems because the file is being read and written at the same time.

Maybe if you store the content in temp file will be better, like so:

```
jq '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords += [{"Value":"${dc1ip}"}]' change.json > temp.json && mv temp.json change.json
```

Comment: I can try that but it's a little weird that it has added a `+` within `cat + jq` when it should ideally be `cat change.json` and then using jq to add a value within `ResourceRecords` list

Comment: So `cat change.json` will run first and then `jq` to populate the file with the Value record and then using `tee` to output to change.json. Weirdly , it never did `cat change.json` but only `cat + jq`